# Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka

When I submit the spark application, getting the below error:

Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V

Went through the below URL:
http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/testing-the-kafka-0-10-connector-td17956.html

Set the below environment variable:
`SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10`

Added the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0.cloudera1</version>
</dependency>
```

Added the below jar:
spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11.jar

Versions I'm using:

- Spark-2.0.2
- Scala-2.11
- Kafka-0.10

A piece of code:

```
val CLASS_NAME = this.getClass
val log = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(CLASS_NAME)
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try seting this:

> export SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10

Comment: THANK YOU! This helped me get past the annoying method not found error. You saved my day.

Comment: Why is it  required ?

Comment: Yeah, why is this required?